# Unable to resolve react jsx-runtime

Tags: reactjs, jsx, yarnpkg

Unable to resolve react jsx-runtime while using react-aspect-ratio dependency in our application

```
-    "react-aspect-ratio": "^1.0.50",
+    "react-aspect-ratio": "^1.1.4",
```

Running the following command mentions, that we are missing jsx-runtime

```
$ node ./sitemap-generator.js
[]
$ export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096 && NODE_ENV=production react-scripts build && webpack --config webpack.server.js
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-aspect-ratio/dist/es/react-15.6.js
Cannot find module: 'react/jsx-runtime'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: yarn add react/jsx-runtime.
```

Running the following command fails

```
yarn add react/jsx-runtime
yarn add v1.22.19
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/react/jsx-runtime.git
Directory: /home/rajesh/work/projects/p/shopdrop-web
Output:
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```